# How to serialize json data coming from two url's in same object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have two url's (urlA and urlB) and both the url gives me json response back in the same json format. Below is my JSON String which I am getting back by calling from urlA. I have shorten it down by having only three `reportRecords` for the understanding purpose. In general, it might have more than ~500 `reportRecords`

```
{
   "aggRecords": {
      "reportRecords": [
         {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 12,
            "avg": 0.3699187,
            "count": 246,
            "sumSq": 571,
            "stddev": 1.4779372,
            "median": 0,
            "percentileMap": {
               "95": 4
            },
            "metricName": "TransactionDuration",
            "dimensions": {
               "env": "dev",
               "pool": "titan",
               "Name": "PostProcessing",
               "Type": "PostProcessing"
            },
            "value": 91
         },
         {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 23,
            "avg": 2.3991289E-4,
            "count": 1463031,
            "sumSq": 3071,
            "stddev": 0.045814946,
            "median": 0,
            "percentileMap": {
               "95": 0
            },
            "metricName": "TransactionDuration",
            "dimensions": {
               "env": "dev",
               "pool": "titan",
               "Name": "ResourceContext",
               "Type": "ResourceContext"
            },
            "value": 351
         },
         {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1209,
            "avg": 1.9203402,
            "count": 7344636,
            "sumSq": 71832774,
            "stddev": 2.4683187,
            "median": 2,
            "percentileMap": {
               "95": 4
            },
            "metricName": "TransactionDuration",
            "dimensions": {
               "env": "dev",
               "pool": "titan",
               "Name": "Client::Sync",
               "Type": "Client::Sync"
            },
            "value": 14104200
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Similarly I am also getting another JSON response back by calling `urlB` and it is in exact same json format as shown above. Now with the below code I am able to serialize above json response coming from `urlA` in `DataTransactionMetrics` object only.

```
public class JSONParser {
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static final String URLA = "urlA";
    private static final String URLB = "urlB";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonTransactionLine = restTemplate.getForObject(URLA, String.class);
        System.out.println(jsonTransactionLine);

        JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonTransactionLine);
        JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
        jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("aggRecords");
        JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("reportRecords");

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<DataTransactionMetrics>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<DataTransactionMetrics> serializeRecord = gson.fromJson(jarray, type);

        // how can I serialize json data coming from URLB to serializeRecord object as well?
    }
}
```

And below is my `DataTransactionMetrics` class -

```
public class DataTransactionMetrics {

    private String metricName;
    private Map<String, Integer> percentileMap;
    private String median;
    private String stddev;
    private String sumSq;
    private String count;
    private String avg;
    private String max;
    private String min;

    // getters here

    public Dimensions dimensions;

    class Dimensions {
        private String env;
        private String pool;
        @SerializedName("Name")
        private String name;

        // getters here
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

How do I serialize json response coming from urlB as well in same `serializeRecord` object so that all the data from both the url (urlA and urlB) are present in same `serializeRecord` object? Is this possible to do?

Comment: I think, Spring already provides a `HttpMessageConverter` to convert from JSON to Java Objects. So you should be able to directly retrieve your Java bean instead of parsing the string manually-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the same for `urlB` too and concatenate both result lists:

```
static final Type listOfMetricsType = new TypeToken<List<DataTransactionMetrics>>() {}.getType();

private List<DataTransactionMetrics> loadMetrics(String url) {
    String jsonString = restTemplate.getForObject(URLA, String.class);

    JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray jarr = json.getAsJsonObject("aggRecords").getAsJsonArray("reportRecords");

    return gson.fromJson(jarr, listOfMetrics);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<DataTransactionMetrics> metrics = loadMetrics(URLA);
    metrics.addAll(loadMetrics(URLB));

    // metrics now contains all metrics (from URLA and URLB)
}
```